# Partisan/Partial Game Theory

Tags: algorithms, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

There are enough resources available on the internet regarding "impartial" game theory. But I cannot seem to find much information regarding "partial" game theory. Can someone name some such resources to study more about partial games?

Comment: Cross-posted on cs: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/17870/partial-partisan-game-theory.

Comment: Berlekamp does initial some Go endgame analysis in [Winning Ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winning_Ways_for_your_Mathematical_Plays), as I recall.  There is also confusion in the general public as to what constitutes an impartial vs. partisan game.  (A not uncommon question is whether Reversi is impartial or partisan.  *It's partisan because the players are using different sets of tokens, and each token set is only available to a single player*;)

Answer (score 2):

The more common spelling in this context is "partizan". And actually, many resources for combinatorial game theory that don't specify partizan/impartial are primarily about partizan games.

The answers to [Reference for combinatorial game theory.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287761/reference-for-combinatorial-game-theory) are basically the things I'd suggest, as almost every introduction to CGT gets to the partizan case early, if not at the very beginning.